# Using typehead.js to search data and retrieve with ajax?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, angularjs, ajax

I have an old autocomplete.js code and with modification I tried to migrate it to typehead.js. The problem is I quite didn't find any results similar to angular and ajax.

Here's my script.

```
$('#empid').typeahead({

        minLength: 1,
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({

                url: "http://localhost:2222/api/search/PostSearch",
                type: "POST",
                data: "{'eid':'" + document.getElementById('empid').value + "'}",
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    response(jQuery.parseJSON(data));
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Here's my angular controller for this

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('efutures.hr.controllers.Search', [])
        .controller('SearchController', SearchController);

    SearchController.$inject = ['$scope', '$location', '$rootScope', '$http', 'AuthenticationService', 'SearchService'];
    function SearchController($scope, $location, $rootScope, $http, AuthenticationService, SearchService) {

        (function initController() {
        })();

        $scope.searchb = function () {
            $scope.searchedDetail.id
            var empid = {
                id: $scope.searchedDetail.id || 'default',
                name: $scope.searchedDetail.ename || 'default'
            };
            SearchService.search(empid, function (res)
            {
                console.log(res.data);
                $scope.empdetails = JSON.parse(res.data);

            });

        };

    }

})();
```

And finally the html

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <!-- col-lg-12 start here -->
        <div class="panel panel-default plain toggle panelMove panelClose panelRefresh">
            <!-- Start .panel -->
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">Basic Data tables</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 control-label" for="">Employee id</label>
                    <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-9">
                        <input id="empid" ng-model="searchedDetail.id" type="text" class="form-control" name="empid" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- End .form-group  -->

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 control-label" for="">Employee name</label>
                    <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-9">
                        <input  id="ename" ng-model="searchedDetail.ename" type="text" class="form-control" name="ename">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- End .form-group  -->
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12 col-sm-offset-3">
                        <button id="btnSearch" type="submit" ng-click="searchb()" class="btn btn-default pad">Search</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <table id="basic-datatables" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>First Name</th>
                            <th>Last Name</th>
                            <th>Date Of Birth</th>
                            <th>Gender</th>
                            <th>email</th>
                            <th>mobile no</th>
                            <th>designation</th>
                            <th>date of join</th>
                            <th>nic</th>
                            <th>department name</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr ng-repeat="emp in employes" style="text-align:center">
                            <td>{{emp.fname}}</td>
                            <td>{{emp.lname}}</td>
                            <td>{{emp.DOB}}</td>
                            <td>{{emp.gender}}</td>
                            <td>{{emp.email}}</td>
                            <td>{{emp.mobile_no}}</td>
                            <td>{{emp.designation}}</td>
                            <td>{{emp.date_of_join}}</td>
                            <td>{{emp.nic}}</td>
                            <td>{{emp.department_name}}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- End .panel -->
    </div>
    <!-- col-lg-12 end here -->
</div>
}
```

Help would be greatly appreciated. I have been asking this question quite some time with no result. So can anyone kindly help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens (or not)? Do you get any empty results?

Comment: @Dejan.S I get results in the cosole. (googgle/ firebug). for e.g. if I type 0032. The results coming to the console as Jason string.

Comment: @Dejan.S Hi! Do you know how to do it? Can you kindly help me?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at this code example I did with typeahead a few weeks ago [codepen](http://codepen.io/tfdbloom/pen/yJqJZP/), you can fork it to change parameters ect...

I think the most interesting parts for you there are the bloodhound to handle data. Try this out and do the modifications needed for your api url that you had in your ajax call.

```
var carData = new Bloodhound({
  remote: {
    url: 'https://api.github.com/users/%QUERY/repos',
    wildcard: '%QUERY'
  },
  datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('name'),
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace
});

$('#empid').typeahead({
     minLength: 1,
    }, {
     name: 'cars',
     display: 'full_name', //your display property here from the json
     source: carData
});
```

Comment: Thanks I'll try it out.